# Angular2 @ViewChild error for component nested in ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with ng2-select. To fetch the data dynamically, I'm following this method:

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select/issues/635

So first I select the component like so:

HTML:

```
<form #frecipientAddAccount="ngForm" novalidate>
     <ng-select #recipientBanks (selected)="selected($event)" placeholder="Select Bank"></ng-select>
```

componen.ts:

```
@ViewChild('recipientBanks') recipientBanks: SelectComponent
```

And I create the option elements with the fetched data like so:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    (<any>this.recipientBanks).items = []
    let currencyTypeId = this.determineCurrencyType();
    let response = getRecipientBanksForCountry(this.data.dashboard.userCountryId, 'C', currencyTypeId);
    response.then((data) => {
        (<any>this.recipientBanks).items = data.list.map(function (obj) {
            return new SelectOptionComponent(obj.BankId, obj.Description)
        })
    })
}
```

And it is working so far. The problem is that the `ng-select` element needs to be nested in a couple of `ngIf` elements, but if I do so, suddenly the component `(<any>this.recipientBanks)` is undefined.

How can I still select the component when it is nested in `ngIf`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having the `#recipientBanks` in the div use it as below,

```
@ViewChild(SelectComponent) recipientBanks: SelectComponent
```

Update 1 :

Instead of using the ViewChild object and assign the properties you can use different object as the ViewChild() turns out to be undefined unless it is rendered in the DOM

```
 <ng-select #recipientBanks (selected)="selected($event)" [items]="dropDownItems" placeholder="Select Bank"></ng-select>
```

Assign the data to `dropDownItems` variable instead of `<any>this.recipientBanks).items`

Alternatively you can use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`

Comment: Based on the linked solution, I should not assign `[items]` attribute in the markup if I want to use dynamic data. Also, I cannot use `[hidden]' for my case.

Comment: Actually it works with `[items]` attribute in the markup...!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit`, and now it works!

Comment: also this is not a best practice too.

Comment: @Aravind Why is it?

Comment: memory consumption will be more